# why not verified form?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.

I made a form in which there is a field select:

```
class DrumDataForm(forms.ModelForm):            
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'drum_photo', 
            'teacher', 
            'drummers',
        )
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    CHOICES_teacher = (
        ('0', '0', ),
        ('1', '1',),
        ('2', '2', ),
    )       

    drum_photo = models.ImageField(
        'ph',
        upload_to='userprofile/drum_photo/', 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    teacher = models.CharField(
        'te',
        max_length=30, 
        choices=CHOICES_teacher,        
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )   
    drummers = models.CharField(
        'dr',
        max_length=300, 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def drum_data_page(request):            
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DrumDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():         
            entry_user = User.objects.get(username__exact=request.user.username)
            entry_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id__exact=entry_user.id)
            entry_user_profile.drum_photo = form.cleaned_data.get('drum_photo')
            entry_user_profile.teacher = form.cleaned_data.get('teacher')
            entry_user_profile.drummers = form.cleaned_data.get('drummers').strip()
            entry_user_profile.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/userprofile/drum_data_page_changed/')
    else:
        entry_user = User.objects.get(username__exact=request.user.username)
        entry_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id__exact=entry_user.id)
        arg = {
            'drum_photo': entry_user_profile.drum_photo,
            'teacher': entry_user_profile.teacher,
            'drummers': entry_user_profile.drummers,
        }

        form = DrumDataForm(arg)        

    t = loader.get_template('drum_data_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
        'drum_photo': arg['drum_photo'],
    }, [custom_proc])
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

if the user makes a selection in the "select" (0, 1, or 2), then the form is submitted. unless the user makes a selection in the "select" (None), the shape of the break and displays the following error message:

```
UnboundLocalError at /userprofile/drum_data_page/
local variable 'arg' referenced before assignment
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/userprofile/drum_data_page/
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'arg' referenced before assignment
```

I need that in any case, the form did not break

Comment: Did you forget to include the error message?

Comment: sorry. add error message text now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing your initial data to the form in the wrong place in the GET block: it's being interpreted as the data. You should do this:

```
form = DrumDataForm(initial=arg)
```

Except that you shouldn't be trying to pass initial data at all with a ModelForm, you should pass the actual instance you want to edit:

```
form = DrumDataForm(instance=entry_user_profile)
```

There are a couple of other issues with your code. Firstly, you don't need to query User via `request.user.username`: `request.user` is *already* the relevant User object.

Secondly, when you come to save, you should again use the `instance` argument and save the ModelForm directly, rather than setting values individually:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DrumDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=my_user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
```

Finally, you should not be extending User with your UserProfile model, but you should extend AbstractUser and set the AUTH_MODEL setting to point to UserProfile: then `request.user` will be an instance of your custom user model.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize Your `arg` variable in case when `request.method` is different than 'POST'. To avoid this error initialize `arg` variable at the top of method.

```
@login_required
def drum_data_page(request):
    args = {}

    entry_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user_ptr_id__exact=request.user.id)            
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DrumDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():         

            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/userprofile/drum_data_page_changed/')
    else:

        form = DrumDataForm(instance=entry_user_profile)        

    t = loader.get_template('drum_data_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
            'form': form,
            'drum_photo': entry_user_profile.drum_photo,,
            },
            [custom_proc])
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Generally @daniel-roseman explain it very well.